# How to make MKS Integrity projects inactive?

Tags: project, version-control-migration, mks-integrity

How to make an mks project inactive so, that users can not perform any actions on it.

This is required for the projects moved to another source control system.

We are moving some projects to svn repository so, We should not allow users not to perform any operations on migrated projects.

Answer (score 1):

Solution I have implemented is to get list of project related ACL's and get list of groups, from groups I have moved all users to Browser group. Browser group is configured to allow users to have readonly permissions.